# Finding the higest voted Question in last week. (sql query)

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have a 3 sql tables:

```
qotwQuestion1a(QuestionId [primarykey], Question, MemberId, PostDate);
qotwVote1a (QuestionId [primarykey], MemberId [primarykey], Vote1a);
qotwMember (MemberId [primarykey], Name, Password, emailId);
```

I want to write a sql query to find the QuetionId and MemberId of the Question that has the highest vote in the last week. I have written this query in php, but it gives me a wrong result:

```
$result6 = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(Vote1a) AS highestVote, * FROM qotwMember, qotwQuestion1a , qotwVote1a
                    WHERE   qotwMember.MemberId=qotwQuestion1a.MemberId 
                    AND     qotwQuestion1a.QuestionId=qotwVote1a.QuestionId 
                    AND     qotwQuestion1a.MemberId=qotwVote1a.MemberId
                    AND     PostDate>='".$startofweek."' AND PostDate<='".$endofweek."'
                    ORDER BY qotwQuestion1a.QuestionId DESC ");
while($row6 = mysql_fetch_array($result6))
  {
  echo "The highest voted question of the last week is: "; echo $row6['highestVote']; echo $row6['MemberId'] . " " . $row6['Name'] . " " . $row6['Password'] . " " . $row6['PostDate'] . " " . $row6['Question']." ".$row6['QuestionId']." ".$row6['Vote1a'];
  echo "<br />";
  }
```

The `$startofweek` and `$endofweek` give the date of the beginning of the last week and end of the last week.

Can someone help me with this, please.

Best
Zeeshan

Comment: You mention in a comment below that you want all questions with the highest vote. You should mention that in your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  q.QuestionId, q.MemberID
        FROM    qotwQuestion1a q
        JOIN    qotwVote1a v
        ON      v.QuestionID = q.QuestionID
        WHERE   PostDate BETWEEN $startdate AND $enddate
        GROUP BY
                q.questionID
        ORDER BY
                COUNT(*) DESC
        LIMIT 1
        ) qo
JOIN    qotwMember m
ON      m.MemberID = q.MemberID
```

Comment: I used you code...Still gives me the error:
 "PHP Warning:  mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource"

Comment: Try to run it in `MySQL Query Browser`, to separate `PHP` problems from `MySQL` problems.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all, using `MAX()` without groupping is .. useless, you don't need it in this case. Second, if you want your results ordered from highest voted down to lowest voted, why don't you order by `Vote1a` and just take the first result with a `LIMIT` clause.

Comment: You did not get my question, i need the just the one entry with the highest vote. or if there are more than one question with the same highest vote .. all of those questions

Comment: Well my suggestion still applies, but it gets more complicated with the requirement of getting ALL rows with the highest vote. In this case, you can write a simple joined select with a WHERE close, which selects the rows with the highest vote, which you can get in a subquery, something in the lines of 

SELECT Vote1a AS highestVote, * FROM qotwMember, qotwQuestion1a , qotwVote1a
<...>
WHERE     qotwVote1a.Vote1a = ( select max(Vote1a) from qotwVote1a group by Vote1a )

I've ommited the join part, because of the length restriction - this is just pseudocode, I'm not sure it works as is :)

Answer (score 0):

Hope you're dealing with ties somewhere ;)

And questions with no answers, for that matter.

Other than that...it looks like you're matching the member to the question, which might not make sense if your tables are set up the way they appear to be.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

SELECT Vote1a AS highestVote, * 
FROM qotwMember, qotwQuestion1a , qotwVote1a
WHERE qotwMember.MemberId=qotwQuestion1a.MemberId 
AND qotwQuestion1a.QuestionId=qotwVote1a.QuestionId 
AND qotwQuestion1a.MemberId=qotwVote1a.MemberId
AND PostDate>='".$startofweek."' 
AND PostDate<='".$endofweek."'
GROUP BY Votela, * 
HAVING MAX(Votela)
ORDER BY qotwQuestion1a.QuestionId DESC");

Not too sure on the syntax of this one but the basic idea is to have a query that can get all records, and then at the last minute, isolate it to just those records having the MAX(Votela).

I would also recommend not using * unless you absolutely need it. I know it can be a pain if you want most of the columns in the tables, but it is always best practice to only select the columns you need.